# perf have no permission to collect stats

Tags: linux, performance, permissions, perf

When I use perf to collect system stats, like this

```
sudo perf record -a -g -F 997 -p pid sleep 30
```

then I got

```
Error:
You may not have permission to collect stats.
Consider tweaking /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid:
 -1 - Not paranoid at all
  0 - Disallow raw tracepoint access for unpriv
  1 - Disallow cpu events for unpriv
  2 - Disallow kernel profiling for unpriv
```

I have no permission to modify `/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid`, even in `root`.
I try to add `"kernal.perf_event_paranoid=-1"` into `/etc/sysctl.conf`, and use

```
sysctl -p
```

to reload params.
Again I have no permission to load param kernal.perf_event_paranoid.

How can I use perf to collect stats?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/980632/run-perf-without-root-rights for modifying `perf_event_paranoid`.

Comment: Is there a misprint in "kernal.perf_event_paranoid=-1" parameter name?

Comment: Note that I'm seeing this even with `perf_event_paranoid = -1`

Comment: Did you try `sysctl -p` with `sudo`?